# Display data same data attribute name within the same class with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to output data attribute values to a dialog box - with the same name, within the same class with an on click event. I have tried to use $(this) selector, but I realize that I am calling from within the same class.

```
<div class="row product_row">
  <div id="pop_up" title="This is The Header" style="display:none;">

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-2 product_description mr- 
                          auto d-flex align-items-center ">
    <p class="fade" id="description2" data-caption="Second 
                           caption set.">
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 mr-auto d-flex align-items-center">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="images/oil.png" />
  </div>
</div>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.product_row').on('click', function() {

      $(function() {
        var text = $(this);
        var text = $('.fade').attr('data-caption');
        $('#pop_up').dialog().html(text);
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your description is somewhat confusing.

If you intend to have the value of data attribute within the same block only. Here is the solution:

```
<div class="row product_row">
  <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-2 product_description mr- 
                          auto d-flex align-items-center ">
    <p class="fade" id="description2" data-caption="Second 
                           caption set.">
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 mr-auto d-flex align-items-center">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="images/oil.png" />
  </div>
</div>
  <div id="pop_up" title="This is The Header" style="display:none;">

  </div>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.product_row').on('click', function() {
        var elt = $(this);
        var text = elt.find('.fade').data('caption');
        $('#pop_up').dialog().html(text);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Some soggestions:
Use [data](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) method instead of attr as it uses cache.

Comment: Thank you Aditya. I am able to call the second attribute, but the first is still null. Any suggestions as to why? Thank you again.

Comment: It's quite confusing with the first & second attribute to understand. Can you be more elaborative or it would be better if you could share a jsfiddle.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Here is a link to your script. The event only fires once.

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/iamaditya/rdqt2bs4/1/ move popup div outside and change js code I will update the comment

Comment: Aditya, thank you. Moving the popup div outside makes sense. I will be sure to review. Thanks again!

Comment: The find method wasn't working. I was able to replace with the closest method and that seemed to solve my problem. Thank you again. Here is the update. https://jsfiddle.net/ericb14/rdqt2bs4/73/